# Why is this function being called?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify some behavior of a framework's JavaScript. In IE10's developer tools under the *View source* drop down, there is a folder called *Dynamic Scripts*. (Maybe someone could explain what Dynamic Scripts are?) And there is the following code under *Function code (1089)*
This is the code:

```
function anonymous() {
var f=arguments.callee; return f._func.apply(f._owner, arguments);
}
```

And the first entry of the call stack is

```
Function code, Function code (1089), line 2
```

This line gets executed several times. But I don't know why.

Who calls this line?

Comment: what framework are you modifying?  What file is that function in?

Comment: It seems not to be in any file. The framework is `Oracle ADF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `anonymous` function call does not mean a function called `anonymous`.  It is actually a name that is used to classify unnamed functions, like this one:

```
var anUnnamedFunc = function() {
    return true;
};
```

If you referenced this function in a watch or console output, it would be dumped as an anonymous function.  To define a function that isn't anonymous, you would use:

```
var aNamedFunc = function namedFunction() {
    return true;
};
```

The function being called in question, looks a lot like a `bind` function.  That is a wrapper function used to create a function that binds arguments and or context to another function.  However, this version uses some sort of private property mechanism to bind arguments:

```
var bind = function() {
    var f = arguments.callee;
    return f._func.apply(f._owner, arguments);
};
```

I actually don't see what this sort of function would be used for, so wonder if it is just an anomaly of the IE debugger.  Try using a different browser and see if that function appears in the profile report.